# Determine whether the following sets are convex or not, and explain your reasoning

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Here are the sets:

1. $C_1 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_2^2 = 1 \}$
2. $C_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : max_{i=1, 2, ..., n}  x_i \le 1 \}$
3. $C_3 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : min_{i=1, 2, ..., n}  x_i \le 1 \}$
4. $C_4 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : max_{i=1, 2, ..., n}  |x_i| \ge 1 \}$

For some reason these all seem convex to me, here are my reasons:

1) This is a norm and thus convex.

2) Let $x, y \in C_2$ and $t \in [0, 1]$. Then $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \:  x_i \le 1$ and $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: y_i \le 1$. If $tx_i + (1-t)y_i \in C_2$ then the set is convex. Consider $$max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: (tx_i + (1-t)y_i)$$

$$=tmax_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: x_i + (1-t)max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: y_i.$$

Since $t$ and $(1-t) \le 1$, and since $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \:  x_i \le 1$ and $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: y_i \le 1$, we know that $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: (tx_i + (1-t)y_i) \le 1$ and thus $tx_i + (1-t)y_i \in C_2$ so the set is convex.

3) The logic seems to be the same as for 2), just replacing the $max$ with $min$.

4) Let $x, y \in C_4$ and $t \in [0, 1]$. Then $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: |x_i| \ge 1$ and $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: |y_i| \ge 1$. Like before, consider
$$max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: (t|x_i| + (1-t)|y_i|)$$

$$=tmax_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: |x_i| + (1-t)max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: |y_i|$$

Again, since $t$ and $(1-t) \le 1$, and since $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \:  |x_i| \ge 1$ and $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: |y_i| \ge 1$, we know that $max_{i=1, 2, ..., n} \: (t|x_i| + (1-t)|y_i|) \ge 1$ and thus $t|x_i| + (1-t)|y_i| \in C_4$ so the set is convex.

These seem correct to me but I feel like at least one of these is not convex for some reason. Can someone check my proofs?

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: The question is about convex *sets*, not convex functions. Your first equation is that of a circle (when $n=2$). Do you really think that every chord of a circle lies on the circle itself?

Answer (score 1):

For a *set* to be convex, every line segment connecting two points in it must lie entirely within the set.

Before you worry about these for general $n$, you should consider them for $n = 2$.

1. is a circle (just the circle itself, not a disk).
2. is a quadrant of the plane, with vertex at $(1,1)$.
3. is the complement of a quadrant of the plane.
4. is the complement of a solid square.

Which of those shapes have points that cannot be connected by a straight line without leaving the set?

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I'm understanding your comment correctly, 1 would not be convex, 2 is convex, 3 would not be convex, and 4 would not be convex. Is this right or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @user591271 - that is correct. Since 1,3,4 fail in the special case $n=2$, the general case (which must hold for all $n$) is also not true. case 2 must still be shown to hold in general, not just for $n=2$. You need to figure out why your arguments for 3 and 4 were wrong (for 1, you were mixing up "convex function" with "convex set") and then revisit your argument for 2.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unsure why my argument for case 2 was wrong. If I can show that for $x, y \in C_2$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, that $tx + (1-t)y \in C_2$, then I prove that $C_2$ is convex, right?

Comment: If you can show that by valid means, then yes. However, you haven't shown it by valid means. The same error that led you to deduce falsely that 3 was convex also exists in your argument for 2. 2 is convex, but your argument doesn't work.

Comment: I've been looking at my work but can't see the mistake. Where did I go wrong exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not handing you the solution on a platter. You will learn more by figuring it out yourself. Did you do as I said, and examine what went wrong for cases 3 and 4? For 3, consider, the line segment running from $(2,1)$ to $(1,2)$. It starts and ends in the set, but every other point is outside it. Now consider your argument in that case. What goes wrong with it? The problem isn't min vs max. It is an assumption you've made that just isn't true. As the argument for 3 is the same as the argument for 2, this false assumption is in 2 as well.